# Going back/forward to a command in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
        Console.WriteLine('What is your name, traveler?');
        string mainName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine('So, your name is ' + mainName + ' ? y/n');
        char ans = Console.ReadKey;
        if (ans == y) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine('Nice, let me introduce myself now.');
        }
        else if(ans == n)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine('Please insert either y or n.');
        }
```

In the code above, how can I make it so that the `else if` statement will return to the third line and the `else` statement will return to the first line of the code and continue running from there?

Comment: Your code might not be compiled.

Comment: There are the `using System;` statements too, but I just put the part that is the part we are looking for.

Comment: `if (ans == y)` should be `if (ans == 'y')`

Comment: moreover you are looking for a `do .. while` loop ... do little more investigation on it and you will be moving soon

Comment: Thanks! I think a `while` will do. I will try that tomorrow since its now late (22:58) for me.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you actually mean you want to return to the beginning in the "else if', and to line 3 in the "else".  You could either use two nested loops, or a single nested loop with a flag to determine whether you need to prompt for the name again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `do....While(true)` loop

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your name, traveler?");
string mainName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("So, your name is " + mainName + " ? y/n");
do
{
    var ans = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
    if (ans == ConsoleKey.Y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nice, let me introduce myself now.");
        break;
    }
    else if (ans == ConsoleKey.N)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Please insert either y or n.");
} while (true);
```

**Note**

I would use `Console.ReadKey(true).Key` to get keyboard input value,because it's enum.

Comment: This will probably do it. I'll try it in a few minutes.